# Finding total distance travelled by a bouncing ball

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program that figures out how many times a ball has dropped given the initial height and the coefficient of restitution. I'm having trouble figuring out how to track the total distance bounced by the ball, here is what I have so far.

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnAnalyze_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAnalyze.Click
    Dim Coef = CDbl(txtRes.Text)
    Dim Height = CDbl(txtHeight.Text)
    Dim NHeight As Double = Coef * Height
    Dim Count As Integer = 0
    Dim Distance As Double
    Dim NDistance As Double
    Do While NHeight > 0.1
        NHeight = NHeight * Coef
        Distance = Height + 2 * NHeight
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop
    lblHeight.Text = CStr(Distance)
    lblBounce.Text = CStr(Count + 1)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: why don't you print out the distance for each iteration of the loop and verify if it's good?

Comment: I would create a variable to contain the total distance and add the individual bounce distances to it...

Comment: You should explain much clearer what you are after. "Total distance" is very ambiguous and can be understood in different ways (even in case of considering a 2D situation). Even "coefficient of restitution" can be understood/applied in different ways (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution). The less clear is your question, the longer it will take it to be answered (and the more likely it might be downvoted/closed).

Comment: @varocarbas genuinely intrigued what else could be meant by total distance in this situation?  I'm probably being naive but the question seemed fairly clear to me...

Comment: @MattFellows I don't know perhaps it is because I have a more or less solid background in physics and on modelling different phenomena and cannot intuitively see a simple interpretation. But when you tell me about a ball bouncing, I see a really difficult problem (-> thinking 3D). By reducing it to 2D, you would have the X and Y movements; for example: at time 0, it would be in x = 0 and y = 0; at time 1 in x = 1 and y = 0.5 and at time 2 in x = 2 and y = 0. I see a pretty complex behaviour there. You are moving certain distance in x global, in x between two y = 0, in y global/average, etc...

Comment: @MattFellows ... that is: you are trying to model a 2D space (I insist, by assuming that this is the case, which wasn't in the description either) by relying on a 1D variable. Distance (= space = vectorial variable) has as many dimensions as being considered at the given moment (= up to a maximum of 3, logically :)) and arbitrarily reducing it to 1 seems confusing. Additionally, the intrinsic complexity of this bouncing behaviour (even of the coefficient of restitution, as proven above) rises quite a few further questions. I mean... at least to me. I hope that I have solved all your doubts.

Comment: I guess it congress down to experience... I've been set a similar problem in a maths class previously. To calculate the total distance traveled by a bouncing ball dropped vertically with only gravity acting upon it. I simplified the problem being asked by the OP to this problem. Also that seemed to be the problem the code almost solved.

Comment: @MattFellows The whole point of my comment was "please, be more clear" (= better for you, for the helper and for future readers). Talking about a bouncing ball and distance being traveled is intuitively confusing. The fact that you happened to solve the same problem (defined in an equivalently-poorly way) doesn't make it clearer. Otherwise, it would be like "what is the result of a+b+c?" and you coming here and saying "13" (because you both read the full description of the problem). Distance is very ambiguous and has to be adequately defined. Even the equation is very unclear: why are you...

Comment: ... doing `Distance = Distance + (Height + 2 * Nheight)`?! Bear in mind that  (physics') coefficients, mainly the ones in over-simplistic calculations like this one, assume lots of things. Truly speaking, the bouncing (and the reduction in the height/distance) occurs as a results of tons of energy interchanges between the ball (which actually is not a rigid solid) and the floor. Saying that there is a reduction of `Coef` times already represents a huge simplification of the actual reality/conventional calcs. Why should I understand your `Coeff` in the way you do (look the link above)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just setting `Distance` to be the distance in the current bounce inside your loop.  Try summing it in each loop with itself; yielding:

```
...
Do While NHeight > 0.1
    NHeight = NHeight * Coef
    Distance = Distance + (Height + 2 * NHeight)
    Count = Count + 1
Loop
...
```

And don't forget to Initialise `Distance` outside the loop

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work, I'm coming up about 11 short of how much it's supposed to be. Thank you for the right track though

Comment: Are you meant to be considering journey upwards as well as downwards?  Not convinced you have counted both in your current algorithm...  Also not sure why you are adding two to the height, then mutiplying by NHeight?  To me it would make more sense to multiply NHeight by two, then add that to distance.

Comment: Yes, and how I have accounted for that is the doubling of the NHeight variable

Comment: You may want to use some parentheses to make sure the operators take effect in the order you expect?

Comment: Good advice with the order of operations, I realized I had to move the Distance calculation above the NHeight one. Thank you!